# Trigger for sum up on look up relationship field

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a custom object "Quotation" with a field name " Tota Premium"
Related object ( child) : Cover, with a field name " Trans Gross Premium". ( The Quotation object look up field API name in Cover object is " Quotation_Number__c"
I want that whenever new Cover records get added to the Quotation object, all Traans gross premium fields will get add up & reflect in the " Total Premium" field.

i have written a trigger, its showing no errors but also not working, Can anyone plz figure it out where i went wrong. Thanks

```
    trigger trgUpdateCover2 on Cover__c (after insert,after update, after delete,after undelete) {
    List<id> QuotationsIds = new List<id>();
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete || Trigger.isupdate){
        For(Cover__c con1 : Trigger.new){
            QuotationsIds.add(con1.id);

        }
    }
    if(Trigger.isDelete){
        For(Cover__c con1 : Trigger.old){
            QuotationsIds.add(con1.id);

        }
    }
    List<Quotation__c> QuotationsToUpdate = new List<Quotation__c>();
    decimal sum = 0;
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete || Trigger.isupdate){
        For (Quotation__c q: [SELECT id,Total_Premium__c, (SELECT id,Trans_Gross_Premium__c FROM Cover__r) FROM Quotation__c WHERE id =:QuotationsIds]){
            sum = 0;
            for(Cover__c  p : q.Cover__r)
            sum = sum + p.Trans_Gross_Premium__c;
            q.Total_Premium__c  = sum;
            QuotationsToUpdate .add(q);
        }
        try{
            update QuotationsToUpdate ;
        }Catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Exception :'+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    if(Trigger.isDelete){
        For(Quotation__c q : [SELECT Total_Premium__c ,(SELECT id,Trans_Gross_Premium__c FROM Cover__r) FROM Quotation__c WHERE id =: QuotationsIds]){
            sum = 0;
            for(Cover__c  p : q.Cover__r)
                sum = sum + p.Trans_Gross_Premium__c;
            q.Total_Premium__c  = sum;
            QuotationsToUpdate .add(q);
        }


        try{
            update QuotationsToUpdate ;
        }Catch(Exception e){
            System.debug('Exception :'+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use a roll up summary field on Quotation instead of doing this via trigger?

Comment: Hi Nathan, because its look up relationship & i cant change it to master -detail as many records exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ids of cover object in the list QuotationsIds and using that list of cover ids you are querying the records from quotation object.The query is not fetching any records here.Please use the quotation ids instead,

You should use

```
 set<id> QuotationsIds = new set<id>();
```

as you can have more than one cover record that have the same quotation id.

```
 if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete || Trigger.isupdate){
        For(Cover__c con1 : Trigger.new){
            QuotationsIds.add(con1.Quotation_Number__c);

        }
    }
    if(Trigger.isDelete){
        For(Cover__c con1 : Trigger.old){
            QuotationsIds.add(con1.Quotation_Number__c);

        }
    }
```

Also please check whether the field is null before summing it up.

```
for(Cover__c  p : q.Cover__r)
{
if(p.Trans_Gross_Premium__c!=null)
            sum = sum + p.Trans_Gross_Premium__c;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Preya, Thanks a lot for pointing my error. i used your code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here.

```
For(Cover__c con1 : Trigger.new){ 
            QuotationsIds.add(con1.id);//Use the lookup field here instead of id.

        }
```

Comment: Hi Prabhat, Thanks. I used the look up field instead and it worked.

Comment: You can select it as answer. So other people can get the help.